# How can I get a list of the regex definitions ctags uses?

Tags: regular-expression, ctags

I am using [exuberant ctags](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/exuberant-ctags) command line tool.

```
% ctags --version
Exuberant Ctags 5.9~svn20110310, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
```

I would like to get a list of the regex definitions that ctags will use when indexing files.
For example I can see what languages ctags supports with:

```
% ctags --list-languages
BETA
C
C++
C#
Cobol
DosBatch
Eiffel
Erlang
Flex
Fortran
Go
HTML [disabled]
Java
JavaScript
Ruby
Scheme
Sh
SLang
```

Im interested in `Sh`, so  I can see what file extensions will trigger ctags will look for `Sh` identifiers with:

```
% ctags --list-maps=Sh
Sh       *.sh *.SH *.bsh *.bash *.ksh *.zsh
```

Now I would like an output of the regex definition mappings for the `Sh` language, e.g. Im looking for something like:

```
ctags --list-definitions=Sh
```

and it would hopefully print something like

```
--regex-sh=/function[ \t]*([A-Za-z0-9._$()]+)[ \t]*\(/\1/F,function,functions/
--regex-sh=/^[ \t]*(local)?[ \t]*([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)=/\2/v,variable,variables/
```

Is this possible with ctags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

short: it doesn't do that.

long: nothing like that is in the [manual page](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html).

There's no point in asking for a new feature, since it's not been touched for a while (see [website](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)).  There is another website promoting itself as a ["maintained ctags"](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags), but a quick read of its [manual page](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/blob/master/man/ctags.1.rst.in) shows little difference (none of what you're looking for).

If it's important, keep in mind that these projects are *self-service*: if you need a feature, you might get it faster if you do the work.